# Differences between zypper up and zypper dup

Tags: package-management, opensuse, upgrade, zypper

I know that `zypper up` updates the current installed packages and `zypper dup` is supposed to upgrade the whole system to a new version.

But from a technical point of view, what are the differences between these two commands? What happens on my system when I run one or the other?

I'm currently using opensuse 13.2 and I'm considering a switch to tumbleweed; I've read different opinions on what is the best way to update the system, up or dup, and I'd like to learn more about it to have a better understanding of the subject.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18549/package-managers-update-versus-upgrade